# Windows 2003 Server with corrupted performance counters

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, perfmon

One of my Windows 2003 servers has for some reason had its performance counters clobbered:

[image]

I'm about to embark on restoring them to their former glory using the steps in this Microsoft Knowledgebase article:

> [How to manually rebuild Performance Counter Library values](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/300956)

The article reads as if there are two ways to do this:

Either - *Rebuild the base performance counters and then re-add the extensible counters*

Or - *To rebuild all Performance counters including extensible and third-party counters in Windows Server 2003,  type the following commands at a command prompt. Press ENTER after each command.*

```
cd\windows\system32
lodctr /R
```

All of the extensible counter `.ini` files seem  to be present and correct in `C:\WINDOWS\inf\009`.

Can I just go straight to running `lodctr /R`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately no.   Not all performance counters load themselves in via an .INI file, and therefore you will still potentially end up with corrupted performance counter.

What you can do is try lodctr /R first to see if that resolves the problem, and go back to the alternative if that did not solve the issue.   On the one occaision I had to do this, I ran the command first, then (after that fixed nothing) ran the KB, then ran lodctr /R again just to make sure there was no residual effects.

Comment: Luckily for us `lodctr /R` got things back to a good state again.